# as3 sending data to PHP using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, pdo

hey guys i want to send variables using **as3** to **php** via using pdo 
there is my as3 code. I just want to add as3 variables to database.
my.fla

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.events.Event;


gonder_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sendData)

function sendData(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  var urlreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("mydomain/dzak/gonder.php");
  urlreq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 

  var urlvars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 
  urlvars.isim = isim_txt.text;
  urlvars.konu = konu_txt.text;
  urlvars.masa = masa_txt.text;
  urlvars.personel = personel_txt.text;
  urlvars.mesaj = mesaj_txt.text;
  urlreq.data = urlvars;          

  var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (urlreq); 
  loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completed); 
  loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 
  loader.load(urlreq); 
}
```

There is my PHP code. I used PDO.
(gonder.php)

```
<?php

    // database connection
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

    $isim = @$_POST["isim"];
    $konu = @$_POST["konu"];
    $masano = @$_POST["masa"];
    $personel = @$_POST["personel"];
    $mesaj = @$_POST["mesaj"];

    // query
    if($_POST){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sikayet (adsoyad,masano,konu,mesaj,personel) VALUES (:isim,:masano,:konu,:mesaj,:personel)";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':adsoyad'=>$adsoyad,
                      ':masano'=>$masano,
                      ':konu'=>$konu,
                      ':mesaj'=>$mesaj,
                      ':personel'=>$personel));
    }
?>
```

When I execute fla i get some error:

```
at Error$/throwError()
at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
at flash.net::URLVariables()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Comment: Merhaba! Have you tried posting directly to gonder.php?

Comment: No its not avalabile in real-time. I just wanna add variables to MySQL via PDO.

Comment: The title of this post is misleading as there is no way to send 'data to PHP using pdo' from ActionScript.  PDO is a feature of PHP to talk to databases.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Relative path instead of the absolute path. Flash player requires absolute path for the Server Side (PHP) code call which is deployed in running server.

You can make configurable absolute path or you can hard code in your AS3 code. Make sure during testing your PHP Web-Server is running coding with your PHP code stuff.

It will work definitely.

```
Current Value: "mydomain/dzak/gonder.php"
Expected Value: "http://www.mydomain/dzak/gonder.php"
```

Try it like that way.